# Restrict the jQuery Datepicker to current Fiscal year with DateFormat: 'MM-dd'

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Below is the jQuery datepicker I am using in my application & its running great.
Now the problem is I want to restrict it to the current fiscal year & for this I am using:

```
maxDate: '03/30/2013' & minDate:'04/01/2012'
```

But it is not working with the current dateFormat: 'MM-yy' I am using & the worst is I can't change the dateFormat.

```
var postForm = false;
    $(function () {
        $('.Month-Picker').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: false,
            maxDate: '03/30/2013',
            minDate:'04/01/2012',
            dateFormat: 'MM-yy',
            onChangeMonthYear: function () { postForm = true; },
            onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
            },
            beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
                if ((datestr = $(this).val()).length > 0) {
                    year = datestr.substring(datestr.length - 4, datestr.length);
                    month = jQuery.inArray(datestr.substring(0, datestr.length - 5), $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNames'));
                    $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                    postForm = false;
                }
            }
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#aspnetForm").click(function () {
            if (postForm == true) {
                postForm = false;
                var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
            }
        });
    });
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the min & max dates by declaring a Javascript date:

```
$('.Month-Picker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: false,
    maxDate: new Date(2013,3,30),
    minDate: new Date(2012,4,01),
    dateFormat: 'MM-yy',
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can try using following code

```
    $('#User_to_date').datepick({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: false,
        dateFormat: 'MM-yy',
        onChangeMonthYear: function () { postForm = true; },
        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        },
        beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
            if ((datestr = $(this).val()).length > 0) {
                year = datestr.substring(datestr.length - 4, datestr.length);
                month = jQuery.inArray(datestr.substring(0, datestr.length - 5), $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNames'));
                $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                postForm = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

I test using this code in my project and get date in "February-21" format,
Just one change **datepicker** to **datepick**.